# Accessing HA Clusters using multiple floating IPS

Tags: nginx, mysql, load-balancing, high-availability

I have set up two highly available clusters which are used to load balance traffic to NGINX and MySQL respectively. The clusters use NGINX and ProxySQL as the load balancing software, to make them highly available I have setup two nodes in each cluster with two floating IP's allowing me to access both servers at the same time.

I now have the problem of accessing each cluster as each has two IP addresses, this is not so much an issue for the NGINX cluster as I can use Round Robin DNS to access both IP's using a single domain name

I am looking for a way to access the Proxysql cluster using one single address. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Round Robin DNS is not HA.

Comment: I never said it was, I said I was using Round Robin DNS to access both floating IP's of an Active Active HA cluster.